# show path in console (windows cmd) whithout tilde

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd

I can log the path of the directory of my node.js server to the windows console

here is my server.js:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end(" hi there !   " );
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');

var message = __dirname;
console.log(message);        // ???
```

the console logs :

```
 C:\DOKUME~1\ateam\LOKALE~1\ANWEND~1
```

I'd like the console to show the whole path without the tilde

like:

```
C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\ateam\Lokale Einstellungen\Anwendungsdaten
```

how can I accomplish that?

Comment: It works correctly for me. What Windows version? What does `echo %cd%` gives you?

Comment: @Sylvain xp, echo %cd% gives me : 'C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\ateam\Lokale Einstellungen\Anwendungsdaten'